# Can't start app using command react-native run-android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Following this [React Native Tutorial: Building Android Apps with JavaScript](https://www.raywenderlich.com/247-react-native-tutorial-building-android-apps-with-javascript) tutorial. I have the Android Studio open and the emulator running and it´s working I tested with another Android Studio app.

I read in the output below - Building and installing the app on the device and 
also - Starting the app

But the emulator does not show the app, any ideas?
CMD OUTPUT:

> L:\react\PropertyFinder\PropertyFinder>react-native run-android JS
>   server already running. Building and installing the app on the device
>   (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
>
> > Task :app:installDebug Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5X_API_27_Android_8.1_ORIO(AVD) - 8.1.0' for app:debug
> >     Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s 27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
>   'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. Starting the app (adb shell am start -n
>   com.propertyfinder/com.propertyfinder.MainActivity...
>
> L:\react\PropertyFinder\PropertyFinder>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can uninstall the APP from your emulator from settings -> Apps -> Select your app and uninstall

Then follow this

1. Close all the npm Terminal
2. Open a new Command prompt and run **react-native start --reset-cache**
3. Open a new Command prompt and run **react-native run-android**

Answer (score 1):

Answering my self, I run this yesterday so the app was already installed on the emulator.

The cmd command :

```
react-native run-android
```

did not start the app since it´s installed for some reason, I hade to manually start the app on the emulator and then I could continue the tutorial

Comment: If you install ADB, the app will launch itself from the command line

Answer (score 1):

The error says you dont have `adb` installed on your device.

You need to install the adb commands, and make sure they're globally available in your `$PATH`. Here are a few step by step tutorials for it:

> https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/
>
> https://www.xda-developers.com/adb-fastboot-any-directory-windows-linux/

Once you have adb installed, Open your terminal and type

```
adb version
```

to make sure its installed correctly. If you run the command `react-native run-android` again, after removing the app from the device, it should link it to the packager and would work fine.

The problem is Android studio has all the tools, but it only creates an environment inside the Android Studio, and none of the tools are available outside the Android Studio env.